# How can I use the index of an numpy array in place without for loop in python 2.7

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I would like to multiply every element in a numpy array by a constant raised to the power of the index of the array element without a for loop.  I am using python 2.7.

I am new to this and can use a for loop by trying to not do that for no real reason.

This for loop would solve the problem

```py
x = 3
for i in range(test_array.size):
    test_array[i] = test_array[i] * x**i
```

Answer (score 0):

One method would be using `np.vander`:

```
test_array *= np.vander([x], test_array.size, True)[0]
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Often in expressions like this the index can be replaced by an array, `np.arange(n)`:

```
test_array[idx] = test_array[idx] * x**idx
```

and since the `idx` covers all the elements (or rows) of the array, this can be simplified to:

```
idx = np.arange(test_array.shape[0])
y = test_array * (x**idx)
```

---

Comparing this with the `vander` suggestion:

```
In [109]: np.vander([x],10, True)                                                                            
Out[109]: 
array([[    1,     3,     9,    27,    81,   243,   729,  2187,  6561,
        19683]])
In [110]: x ** np.arange(10)                                                                                 
Out[110]: 
array([    1,     3,     9,    27,    81,   243,   729,  2187,  6561,
       19683])
```